# Invalid GTalk scope for device in OAUTH2 authorisation process

Tags: gmail, google-api, oauth-2.0, google-talk

I want my app to be able to log to GTalk and GMail with OAuth2 authentication.
My app runs on feature phones and can't access the internal browser, so I use the "device" OAuth flow as described at [here](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ForDevices).

POST to `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/device/code` returns an `invalid_scope` error (400 HTTP error) with the scope set to GTalk

```
scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/googletalk"
```

If I set the scope to GMail (`https://mail.google.com/`) , it returns the same error, but if I set the scope to Youtube (`https://gdata.youtube.com`) all is working fine.

Is there a "white list" describing source(web, installed app or devices) accessiblity to different scopes, i.e. is OAuth2 authentication not permitted to GTalk and GMail from a device?

If this is the case, J2ME apps running on feature phones will not be able to login anymore to GTalk/Gmail services when OAuth2 will be the only way to log in to these services.

The phones are no smartphones and neither running Android nor iOS!

Answer (score 1):

From Google's [OAuth2 developer group on Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/oauth2-dev/Rc4CJiykhk4/discussion) (where you also posted [this question](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/oauth2-dev/TUN5iBx0bQE/discussion), but got no answer so far):

> Not all scopes are supported to be used with the device flow and that is why you are getting an error.

It would be nice of Google to somewhere document this and state if theses scopes will be enabled for the *Devices* flow later or not.